Android app (Unity game) crash due to process is going to kill itself
I'm working on a mobile game for Android device using Unity Engine.
The game crashes during the initial phase of the game. There are no fatal exceptions or crash logs.
All I see is Module config changed, forcing restart due to module measurement.dynamite and Process is going to kill itself! when this happens.
These crashes are not reported in Firebase Crashlytics for some reason.
This only happens when the device language is changed to a language other than English, and then the game is installed.
Also it happens only once per language change & doesn't happens when the device language is English. We've tried disabling localization as well.
It's more frequent on Mi devices, in Google and Samsung devices the frequency is less.
Unity Version: 2021.3.31f1
Here are the logs from Android Studio during the crash:
2024-07-30 15:24:26.530 23312-26244 DynamiteLoaderV2Impl    com.company.package             I  Module config changed, forcing restart due to module measurement.dynamite
2024-07-30 15:24:26.540 23312-26244 Process                 com.company.package             I  Process is going to kill itself!
                                                                                                    java.lang.Exception
                                                                                                        at android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:1344)
                                                                                                        at m.cs.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@242632038@24.26.32 (190400-0):840)
                                                                                                        at m.cp.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@242632038@24.26.32 (190400-0):22)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
                                                                                                        at m.bv.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@242632038@24.26.32 (190400-0):8)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
2024-07-30 15:24:26.540 23312-26244 Process                 com.company.package             I  Sending signal. PID: 23312 SIG: 9`

We've tried disabling localisation, profiled to check if this is memory issue
Downgraded and removed Firebase SDK and other analytics related SDKs
